# Chrome DevTools Terminology

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools

Sorry if I am asking this in the wrong place, but I just don't know where to ask. So I am debugging the node.js code below:

```
var leakyArr = [];

var gameLoop = function () {

    leakyArr.push(function leakyFunc() {
        return 'BEST FRIENDS!' + leakyVar;
    });

    var leakyVar = -357;

    setTimeout(gameLoop, 500);

    console.log("1");

};

gameLoop();
```

When I make two snapshots and then compare them I get following image:

[image: Snapshots comparison]

Now can you please help me to find out what each of the numbers means? For example, what this "system / Context" under **№1** means? What **№2** means and how it is different from **№1**? I think (hope) that *Array @57617* is my *leakyArr*, is that right? What is **№4** and how it is different from **№2**? What is this **№3** "system / Context" again and how it is different from **№1**? What is **№5**?

Also, can you give me a link to some documentation or article about all that stuff? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: The [documentation article](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/memory-101) is easy to find, not sure it answers all of your questions, though.